# How to segment objects in a image without human interaction using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to use OpenCv methods to segment images.I have come across Grabcut algorithm but this still requires human interaction like drawing a box to circle a object. 
So my question is how to I use OpenCv to do segmentation automatically? Suggestions and code snippet in either C++ or Java are much appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm trying to segment food items from plate and table.

Comment: Can you show us the type of image you want to segment ? There are many ways to cut objects using openCV, but the method depends on the type of object, contrast, etc..

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: You would better show us an actual image of what you want, or else it will not be possible to help you, but here is the basic principle :

Comment: If you have a color image, your food probably has colors different from your plate and table (let's say you want to find a tomatoe and carrot on a white plate on a wooden table). In this case, to select the objects, using color classification is probably the easiest way.

In case you only have grayscale image, you need to have enough contrast on your image in order to detect the edges of your objects (basically how your eyes would do). You can then extract these edges using several algorithms provided by OpenCV. For example you can try using a sobel filter to get the edges

Answer (score 2):

Yes, grabCut requires human interaction, But we can minimize it, like I have personally used grabCut algorithm for segmenting faces from the given image, So it basically involves:

- Detecting face in the given image using haar cascade
- Generating a probability mask, which would help you in generating markers required for the segmentation.

The first part requires you to either use a pre-manufactured [haar cascade](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades), or [create your own](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) by providing sufficient training examples.

Once you have a working haar cascade, you can use it to get ROI for each input image, You may extend the ROI dimensions to include more space around the object.

So Now at this step you must be able to crop your required object from the given input image, which reduces the search domain, Now you can create a probability mask, which would indicate the probable location of object for a given ROI, the previous steps were necessary to normalize the input image, Now we can assume the input is always normalized so the object location would be somewhat consistent w.r.t ROI. Here is a sample probability mask for male Human hair:

[image]

Now you choose 4 thresholds to create mask for grabcut as:

> - if (pix > 220):       mask = cv::GC_FGD
> - else if (pix > 170):  mask = cv::GC_PR_FGD
> - else if (pix > 50):   mask = cv::GC_PR_BGD
> - else:                 mask = cv::GC_BGD

Then you can pass this as mask to perform grabcut segmentation.

However there has been some recent advancements in [semantic segmentation](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~szheng/crfasrnndemo), which uses CRF as RNN technique to segment objects form the given image, it requires no normalization thing, but due to it's dependency on GPU for efficient running, it is not suitable for mobile or low end computer applications.

Comment: Does this work with segmenting food items from plate and table? I just read a bit about haar cascade, it seems used for face detection. Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I already knew you were searching for non-face related haar cascade, that's why I attached this [link](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) in the answer, You need to train your own cascade for that purpose, or search on web if someone has already created one.